# MSB3245:Could not resolve this reference (System.Drawing.Imaging)

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, visual-studio-code, f#-fake

I'm developing F# in Visual Studio Code, and when I try to compile my code with FAKE I get the above error:

`warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Drawing.Imaging". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`

And then a long list of "Considered `<various filepaths>`, but it didn't exist." Including my .NET Framework folder and the GAC, which is strange. I would honestly have expected Imaging to be a namespace declared in `System.Drawing.dll`, but the compiler didn't even seem to consider this option...

I'm getting identical errors with `System.Windows.Media`, `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`, and `System.Windows.Media.IO`. Possibly related is the fact that IntelliSense isn't picking up those namespaces either, though it *does* find System.Drawing.Imaging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, I figured out my problem while writing it up, but figured I might as well post it in case someone else has the same issue.

The root problem is that `>F#: Add Reference` isn't working, by which I mean if I hit `>F#: Add Reference` > `<current project>` > `System.Drawing.Imaging` (say), nothing in particular seems to happen. If someone can solve that and posts their answer I'll accept theirs and upvote it, because that's the real problem.

In order to work around that bug in VSCode, I manually edited my `fsproj` file, but it seems I didn't really understand what I was doing. Apparently it goes looking for explicit dlls when given `<Reference>`s in the format I was using, which of course don't exist for `.Imaging` and the like. Once I removed those the errors went away, without creating new errors for, say, not recognizing `Bitmap` like I would've expected.

UPDATE: The problem with `Add Reference` has now also been found: apparently Ionide doesn't generate correct Forge commands when the username has spaces in it on, say, Windows.